# Copy/Paste or Export/Import a SharePoint online communication site across tenants

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, pnp

I have a communication site which contain 2 SharePoint lists , 2 content types and couple of site columns. now i want to Copy/Paste or Export/Import the SharePoint online communication site across tenants? can i do so using Power Shell or other approaches (free as i only need to do this once for a single site only)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Utilise site templates and upload the site templates to other tenants:

[SharePoint site template and site script overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview)

2. For more complex site provisioning scenarios, consider using the PnP provisioning engine. The PnP PowerShell cmdlets allow you to create templates from existing sites which can then be applied to other sites in other tenants:

[Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)